# Python capture a specific pattern inside a string with regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching, extract

I have a string like this `'6\' 3" ( 190 cm )'` and I would like to extract `'190 cm'` only using regular expressions. I can't find the appropriate pattern to look for.

I have tried

```
string = '6\' 3" ( 190 cm )'
pattern = re.compile(r'[^\\( 0-9+ \\)]')
pattern.findall(a)
```

but it returns
    ["'", '"', 'c', 'm']

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Try `(?<=\()[^)]+(?=\))` or use a capturing group `\(\s*([0-9]+\s*[a-z]+)\s*\)`

Comment: `[0-9]+` or \d+

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thank you very much,it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

too many unrequired and harmful symbols in your expression.

Using surrounding `[]` made `findall` match individual characters, which explains the output you're getting.

This needs a full rethink: escape the parentheses, use `\d+` to match one or more digits, and explicit `cm` and spaces.

create a group to match only digits+unit, use `search` to find the group and display it.

```
import re
string = '6\' 3" ( 190 cm )'
pattern = re.compile(r'\( (\d+ cm) \)')

>>> pattern.search(string).group(1)
'190 cm'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
print re.findall(r'[0-9]+ cm',string)[0]
```

where `string` is:

```
'6\' 3" ( 190 cm )'
```

Answer (score 2):

With regular expressions:

```
import re

s = '6\' 3" ( 190 cm )'
desired_output = re.search(r'\((.*?)\)',s).group(1).lstrip()

print(desired_output)
>>> 190 cm
```

Without regular expressions:

```
s = '6\' 3" ( 190 cm )'
desired_output = s[s.find("(")+1:s.find(")")].lstrip()

print(desired_output)
>>> 190 cm
```

Answer (score 1):

You could  use a capturing group which will be returned by [findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re%20findall#re.findall):

```
\(\s*([0-9]+\s*[a-z]+)\s*\)
```

That will match:

- `\(\s*` match `(` and 0+ times a whitespace char
- `(` Capturing group

  - `[0-9]+\s*[a-z]+` Match 1+ a digit, 0+ times a whitespace char and 1+ times a-z (or use `cm` instead of `[a-z]+` if you want to match that literally)
- `)` Close capturing group
- `\s*\)` Match 0+ times a whitespace char

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/B40WhD/1/) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/wPKSdu)

For example:

```
import re

string = '6\' 3" ( 190 cm )'
pattern = re.compile(r"\(\s*([0-9]+\s*[a-z]+)\s*\)")
print(pattern.findall(string))
```